# Why is there such a large gap in between spark jobs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm writing a somewhat long/complex spark application.  Maybe a few hundred Jobs depending on input.  However, I find my application spends a lot of time doing nothing.  In the image, you can see between the last job and the second to last job there is about a 30 second difference.

The code is not doing anything outside of spark to warrant such a delay.  The first and last line in the following code represents the second to last and last job, respectively

```
zippedEdges.count()

val anRdd = zippedEdges.map {
  case (a, b) => (SomeCaseClass(someMapBroadcast.value(a.someproperty), a.someotherproperty), b)
}.
  join(someRdd, new HashPartitioner(partitions)).map(x => x._2).setName("rddName").persist(caching)
anRdd.count()
```

It isn't a long lineage issue because this particular code operates on a new RDD.  Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and/or how to fix it.  10-30 seconds for hundreds of jobs adds up.

[image: Delay in job start]

Comment: Is there anything happening in the log during those 10/30 seconds?